# Switch Activities without the use of an Intent

Tags: android, android-intent, singleton

I was working on a project and had my Activities passing each other information via Intents. However, I recently decided to swithc and go with the Singleton method and have an Application class holding all of my data.

I'm now a little confused: how do I start my Activities without Intents? This is a call I had before I switched...

```
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected( MenuItem item ) {
    switch( item.getItemId() ) {
    case R.id.connect:
        startActivityForResult( new Intent( this, DeviceList.class ), REQUEST_CONNECT_DEVICE  );
        return true;
```

What would I change it to to start the DeviceList class without the use of intents?

Comment: I don't think you can start an Activity without an Intent. There's nothing I can remember from the documentation

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You don't. Use intents to start your activities. This is how Android is designed.

Comment: Ah that makes plenty more sense to me. I had thought that Intents were only to pass data, not necessarily how the activities were started. Thank you.

Comment: @user1435712 : Reading and understanding the following link will really help.  http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/intents/intents-filters.html

Comment: In addition to the document @Squonk linked to, you might also want to read the [Application Fundamentals doc](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/fundamentals.html) especially the section on [activating components](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/fundamentals.html#ActivatingComponents).

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you can. First, you need to extends [`ActivityGroup`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ActivityGroup.html)

```
public class Activity1 extends ActivityGroup
```

Then, u need to create a method in that class to replace content view, in this case in `Activity1`

```
public void replaceContentView(String id, Intent newIntent) {
    View view = getLocalActivityManager().startActivity(id,newIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP)) .getDecorView(); 
    setContentView(view);   
}
```

When you want to start Activity2 from Activity1,

```
Intent activity2 = new Intent(this, Activity2.class);
replaceContentView(Activity2.class.getName(), activity2 );
```

You can even start Activity3 from Activity2

```
Intent activity3 = new Intent(getParent().getApplicationContext(), Activity3.class);
Activity1 parent = (activity3 ) getParent();
parent.replaceContentView(Activity3.class.getName(), activity3 );
```

Hope this can help

P.S : You can reference [this link](http://www.gamma-point.com/content/android-how-have-multiple-activities-under-single-tab-tabactivity)

Comment: why use Intent in method parameter ? as like :                                         public void replaceContentView(String id, Intent newIntent)

Answer (score 1):

Passing the data between two Activities is not only the roll of the intent.. it passs the Other must required infomration which is must for creating an Activity like `Context`, package info etc

as per deination as [link](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html)

An intent is an a`bstract description of an operation to be performed`.